# Understanding Apple remote receipts

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

This is the code in my iOS project:

```
if let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptURL) {
    //send receipt data.base64EncodedString() to server
}
```

My server code

```
def verify():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    receipt = json_data["receipt"]
    env = json_data["env"]
    bundle_id = json_data["bundle_id"]

    if env == "production":
        endpoint = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
    else:
        endpoint = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"


    applePayload = {
    "receipt-data":             receipt,
    "password":                 "mysecret",
    "exclude-old-transactions": True

    }
    r = requests.post(endpoint, json=applePayload)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    return r.text
```

This is the Apple response when I send the receipt from an test account:

```
{"status":0, "environment":"Sandbox", 
"receipt":{"receipt_type":"ProductionSandbox", "adam_id":0, "app_item_id":0, "bundle_id":"es.mediaregie.wholovesme", "application_version":"2", "download_id":0, "version_external_identifier":0, "receipt_creation_date":"2019-05-11 18:43:58 Etc/GMT", "receipt_creation_date_ms":"1557600238000", "receipt_creation_date_pst":"2019-05-11 11:43:58 America/Los_Angeles", "request_date":"2019-05-14 05:46:18 Etc/GMT", "request_date_ms":"1557812778939", "request_date_pst":"2019-05-13 22:46:18 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1375340400000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles", "original_application_version":"1.0", 
"in_app":[
{"quantity":"1", "product_id":"weekly_subscription", "transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "original_transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:17:20 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1557591440000", "purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:17:20 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:17:22 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1557591442000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:17:22 America/Los_Angeles", "expires_date":"2019-05-11 16:20:20 Etc/GMT", "expires_date_ms":"1557591620000", "expires_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:20:20 America/Los_Angeles", "web_order_line_item_id":"1000000044334416", "is_trial_period":"false", "is_in_intro_offer_period":"false"}, 
{"quantity":"1", "product_id":"weekly_subscription", "transaction_id":"1000000526894809", "original_transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:20:20 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1557591620000", "purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:20:20 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:17:22 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1557591442000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:17:22 America/Los_Angeles", "expires_date":"2019-05-11 16:23:20 Etc/GMT", "expires_date_ms":"1557591800000", "expires_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:23:20 America/Los_Angeles", "web_order_line_item_id":"1000000044334417", "is_trial_period":"false", "is_in_intro_offer_period":"false"}, 
{"quantity":"1", "product_id":"weekly_subscription", "transaction_id":"1000000526895042", "original_transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:23:20 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1557591800000", "purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:23:20 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:17:22 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1557591442000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:17:22 America/Los_Angeles", "expires_date":"2019-05-11 16:26:20 Etc/GMT", "expires_date_ms":"1557591980000", "expires_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:26:20 America/Los_Angeles", "web_order_line_item_id":"1000000044334428", "is_trial_period":"false", "is_in_intro_offer_period":"false"}, 
{"quantity":"1", "product_id":"weekly_subscription", "transaction_id":"1000000526895281", "original_transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:26:20 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1557591980000", "purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:26:20 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:17:22 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1557591442000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:17:22 America/Los_Angeles", "expires_date":"2019-05-11 16:29:20 Etc/GMT", "expires_date_ms":"1557592160000", "expires_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:29:20 America/Los_Angeles", "web_order_line_item_id":"1000000044334441", "is_trial_period":"false", "is_in_intro_offer_period":"false"}, 
{"quantity":"1", "product_id":"weekly_subscription", "transaction_id":"1000000526895686", "original_transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:29:20 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1557592160000", "purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:29:20 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:17:22 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1557591442000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:17:22 America/Los_Angeles", "expires_date":"2019-05-11 16:32:20 Etc/GMT", "expires_date_ms":"1557592340000", "expires_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:32:20 America/Los_Angeles", "web_order_line_item_id":"1000000044334455", "is_trial_period":"false", "is_in_intro_offer_period":"false"}, 
{"quantity":"1", "product_id":"weekly_subscription", "transaction_id":"1000000526896082", "original_transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:32:20 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1557592340000", "purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:32:20 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:17:22 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1557591442000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:17:22 America/Los_Angeles", "expires_date":"2019-05-11 16:35:20 Etc/GMT", "expires_date_ms":"1557592520000", "expires_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:35:20 America/Los_Angeles", "web_order_line_item_id":"1000000044334476", "is_trial_period":"false", "is_in_intro_offer_period":"false"}]}, 
"latest_receipt_info":[
{"quantity":"1", "product_id":"weekly_subscription", "transaction_id":"1000000526896082", "original_transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:32:20 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1557592340000", "purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:32:20 America/Los_Angeles", "original_purchase_date":"2019-05-11 16:17:22 Etc/GMT", "original_purchase_date_ms":"1557591442000", "original_purchase_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:17:22 America/Los_Angeles", "expires_date":"2019-05-11 16:35:20 Etc/GMT", "expires_date_ms":"1557592520000", "expires_date_pst":"2019-05-11 09:35:20 America/Los_Angeles", "web_order_line_item_id":"1000000044334476", "is_trial_period":"false", "is_in_intro_offer_period":"false"}], 
"latest_receipt":"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", 
"pending_renewal_info":[
{"expiration_intent":"1", "auto_renew_product_id":"weekly_subscription", "original_transaction_id":"1000000526894772", "is_in_billing_retry_period":"0", "product_id":"weekly_subscription", "auto_renew_status":"0"}]}
```

According to this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW3  If I understand correctly I should use only the `latest_receipt_info` field to check if the user subscription is currently 
active.

What about if there are more products(consumable, subscriptions, etc)?

It's ok ignore the `latest_receipt` field?

Should I perform any validation of the server response in the iOS device?

Comment: The `latest_receipt` field is only for auto-renewable subscriptions. So you'd still need to check for consumables.

Comment: The 'lastest_receipt' field looks like a hash. What should I do with it?

Comment: The `latest_receipt` field is another receipt file that you can decode with the shared secret to get the information that's in `latest_receipt_info`. You should have everything you need in the `latest_receipt_info` to determine if subscription is still active. Sorry my first comment was unclear.

Comment: @enc_life and what about `latest_receipt_info` looks like the same as `latest_receipt` without ask to Apple again, isn't it?

Comment: Correct, it will contain the same data you don't need to verify with Apple again.